Moving observer detects incoming photon: Is this the full derivation of the relativistic Doppler effect?
I have a very trivial question that I can't quite work out. Imagine an observer moving in Minkowski spacetime. In Cartesian coordinates $(ct,x,y,z)$, their 4-velocity is
$$u^\mu = (u^t ,u^i )$$
where $u^t = c\gamma$ and $u^i = \gamma v^i$ with $v^i =\frac{dx^i}{dt}$
This observer receives a photon with 4-momentum
$$p^\mu = \frac{E}{c}(1,\hat{k})$$
The energy observed is $E_{obs}=-u^\mu p_\mu $, so using the Minkowski metric we get
$$E_{obs}=E\gamma \big(1-\frac{\vec{v}\cdot \hat{k}}{c}\big) $$
This to me makes sense... The factor of gamma in front is the universal blueshift that any moving observer detects due to time dilation. The factor between brackets is the good old Doppler effect: If you are moving  away from the photon it gets redshifter, if you are moving towards it it's blueshifted, if it hits you perpendicularly, it doesn't matter.
Now... to me, this is the derivation of the relativistic Doppler effect. That's it. I understand that I completely neglected the perspective of the source and what energy $E'$ and direction $\hat{k}'$ they measure. In a way, my choice is to parametrize the incoming photon with $E$, which corresponds to the energy that an observer at rest relative to coordinate time would measure. But from the point of view of being a moving observer who detects a photon, this is it, no? Am I missing something?
